# Routes in ionic application with history push state

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

Is it possible to use routes in ionic app? I want to change URL when current component is changed.

I have AppComponent with template: `<ion-nav [root]="rootPage"></ion-nav>`

I change current page using: `this.navCtrl.push(BooksComponent)`

The page is changed but URL is still http://example.com/ I need http://example.com/books

Answer (score 0):

For Ionic 2+ you can use the [DeepLinker](https://ionicframework.com/docs/2.0.0/api/navigation/DeepLinker/) which is already included OOTB.

See here for steps to set it up:

- https://ionicframework.com/docs/2.0.0/api/navigation/DeepLinker/